# Auto Scrolling in Metro App using C# and XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am making this Metro app which has a parent grid with 3 columns. In the col# 1, I have this login form. I want this to come at the center when the app loads. With the Sign Up and Recover passwords in col# 0 and col# 2 respectively. So I put the grid in a scrollviewer: `

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> <!--For Sign Up-->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> <!--For Sign In-->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> <!--To Recover Password-->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>`
```

I don't want to set the width of the grid explicitly. Because then either I would have to optimize the size for very large resolutions or very small. What I want is the col# 1 in the middle with a little of col#0 and col#2 visible at the sides of col#1.

What should I set the width of grid to so that it looks consistent irrespective of the resolution? And how do I auto scroll and bring the col#1 in the middle?

Comment: can u elaborate more on your requirement. Only resolution independence is clear. Other are not that much

Comment: I can't picture what you're trying to do either. I did want to add that you shouldn't do login in the main Metro canvas. You should do login in the settings flyout to be consistent in the Metro environment. You can programmatically trigger the settings flyout to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to capture the screen width programmatically. I'm a HTML/JS dev, so I don't know what the property is in XAML/C#. Then you can set your grid size relative to that. Then if it changes, your grid will be bigger.
As far as the scrolling goes, I think you're looking for something like what I wrote here (http://www.codefoster.com/post/2012/06/24/How-to-Make-Your-Grid-Pan-Automatically.aspx), but you'll have to translate between the JavaScript and C# because I wrote it in JS. Hope that helps.